# Protected member variables in abstract class?

Tags: c++, optimization, abstract-class

```
class A{
public:
    class A() : var1(0)
    {}
    virtual ~A(){};
    virtual void DoMagic() = 0;
protected:
    int var1;
};
```

I'm having some problems with -O optimizations gcc. Then program runs well without the optimization, but crashes in random builds with it, no matter the level.

I have a couple of abstracts classes with protected member variables, like shown above. This variables are actively used by the derived classes. Could this be related?

I heard Scott Meyers advises against this practice, but I can't find the reference text.

Can this be the cause of the problem?
Is this valid c++?

Thank you.

Comment: It might not be the best design, but this is valid C++, and cannot by itself cause the kind of problems you describe. Your problems lie elsewhere.

Comment: did you initialize var1 in constructor? your code is not valid, DoMagic is not virtual.

Comment: Yes, I initialize var1 in class A's initialization list.

Comment: This doesn't look like it would even compile.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add 'virtual' to the example.

Comment: do you see have virtual destructor in class A? please post valid real code

Comment: This is NOT an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) (as evidenced by the fact you missed the 'virtual'). Chances are you are running into splicing or - since you don't name your members properly - variable shadowing.

Comment: When a program *behaves* at one optimization level and it crashes with a different optimization level, more often than not the original program has undefined behavior. The first thing you need to do is use the debugger to find out where and why your program is crashing. If you are lucky the debugger will point to the exact location. If you are less lucky it will give you little information about the root cause, and point only at the symptoms

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem might be else where.

Change:

```
void DoMagic() = 0;
```

to:

```
virtual void DoMagic() = 0;
```

Also make sure you have a virtual destructor.

```
virtual ~A( ) { }
```

When you derive make sure you initialise var1 from the derived constructor before you use it.

```
B::B( ) : var1( 0 ) { }
```

As for design, I don't know the context, in some cases it's okay, but I try avoid it.